# Getting a list of Callbacks that a Tensorflow Model Uses

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Trying to make a callback that gets all the callbacks that a model uses using keras.callbacks.CallbackList.

My (quite frankly dumb) issue is that it's attempting to print the object instead of the list it claims to retrieve.

If I try to print keras.callbacks.CallbackList().callbacks, the list is empty.

Here's my minimal recreation:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D,  GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping, Callback
import numpy as np

class callback_count(Callback):
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        print("Just making sure the callback works!")

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        # I want to get a list of all callbacks used by the function
        callback_list = keras.callbacks.CallbackList()
        print(f"List of callbacks used by function: {callback_list}")
        # ^^ Doesn't work? Certainly me just being dumb w/ python.
        # prints out callback.CallbackList object rather than a list of callbacks.

def model_function():
    inputs = Input((28, 28, 1), dtype=np.float32)
    l = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255., offset=0.0)(inputs)
    l = Conv2D(10, (3, 3))(l)
    l = Conv2D(10, (3, 3))(l)
    l = Conv2D(10, (3, 3))(l)
    l = Conv2D(10, (3, 3))(l)
    l = Conv2D(10, (3, 3))(l)
    l = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(l)
    l = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(l)
    model = keras.Model(inputs, l)
    op = keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-2)
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=op, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# Two other random callbacks!
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_loss", factor=0.25, patience=50, verbose=1, mode="auto", min_delta=1.e-16, cooldown=0, min_lr=2.5e-5,)
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', min_delta=0, patience=150, verbose=1, mode='auto', baseline=None, restore_best_weights=True)

callback_number = callback_count()  # <-- Using the callback

# preparing dataset
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1), np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=-1)


bs, num_epochs = 256, 2000

model = model_function()
hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=bs, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                 callbacks=[reduce_lr, early_stop, callback_number])
```